# Если много людей, то «Вы» или «вы» при обращении?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, обращение

Можете сказать, можно ли писать *вы* с большой буквы при обращении ко многим людям (а не к одному человеку), когда ты хочешь вежливость таки выразить?

Например: *А Вы, господа, узрите моего Мететеха — котика-умника!*

Comment: Я думаю, что написание с большой буквы Вы применимо только к одной персоне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> § 202. С прописной буквы пишутся местоимения *Вы, Ваш* как форма выражения вежливости при обращении к одному конкретному лицу в письмах, официальных документах и т. п., напр.: *Поздравляем Вас..., Сообщаем Вам...; в ответ на Ваш запрос...*
> Так же пишутся слова *Вы* и *Ваш* в текстах, предназначенных для многократного использования, типа анкет, рекламы, листовок.
> С прописной буквы пишутся при официальном титуловании оба слова в сочетаниях *Ваше (Его, Ее) Величество, Ваше (Его, Ее) Высочество*...

Вывод: пишем местоимение "вы" со строчной (оно в этом контексте обращением не является).

И всегда так писали (В Нацкорпусе — 77 примеров):

XVIII век — *Мы ѣздимъ въ срединное государство, и получаемъ отъ превосходнаго Святѣйшаго великаго Хана высочайшую милость съ давныхъ лѣтъ, **а вы господа** послы въ первой разъ къ намъ приѣхали* (А. Л. Леонтьев [перевод отчета Ту Ли-чэня с маньчжурского]. Путешествие китайского посланника к калмыцкому Аюке-хану (**1762**));

XIX век — ***А вы, господа**, разве не танцуете? ― спрашивает Алексей Дмитрич, поводя глазами по стене* (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Губернские очерки (**1856–1857**));

XX век — *Да, без лести предан он был Александру I, **а вы, господа**, преданы П. А. Столыпину, это так, но слова «без лести» вы не можете написать на вашем девизе* (В. В. Шульгин. Последний очевидец (**1971**));

XXI век — ***А вы, господа**, кто?* (Алексей Иванов. Комьюнити (**2012**)).

[Прописные буквы в особом стилистическом употреблении](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=93#pp93) (ПАС)
[А вы, господа...](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Ck8qIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKMbb4/GavNEDQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIwohCh8KA3JlcRIYChbQsCDQstGLINCz0L7RgdC/0L7QtNCwMAE=) (Нацкорпус)

Comment: Римма, а если автор хочет свою вежливость особо подчеркнуть, возможно (и скорее всего) в ироническо-насмешливом смысле? Можно тогда написать Вы? Мне вот это любопытно было.  Есть ли такие случаи?

Comment: Ну... Если только в подчеркнуто ироническом. *А Вы, господа Детишечки, чего изволите?* Детки — маленькие, ничего из себя еще не представляющие, а буковки и амбиции — большие, серьезные.

Comment: Здесь лексика соответствующая такому стилю: УЗРИТЕ моего Мететеха — котика-умника!

Comment: Э-э... Наверно, я чегой-то не понимаю. Узреть — *устар., книжн.* В чём собственно ирония или насмешка, — ну бестолковая! — не улавливаю (тем более что особенный таки автор ни о каком особенном таки смысле не говорил-таки).

Comment: Римма,  я  в ответе  напишу комментарий по отношению к вопросу, а то здесь не помещается.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на заданный вопрос** (в форме пародии)

Можно ли найти в современных правилах **разрешение** на написание ***ВЫ*** по отношению к группе лиц? Это вряд ли, но как-то **оправдаться можно**, если уж сделали замечание. Вот хотя бы так.

*А что, у меня это **стилизация**. Какая? Да хоть бы какая. ***Вежливая***, например.*

*Потому что я использую **устаревшую лексику** (***узреть***) в современном тексте. **Господ** у нас опять же  нет.. Если только ***господин посол,*** но это официальный стиль.*

**Что с того?** Просто я рассуждаю так. В правилах Розенталя и Лопатина выбор прописной буквы связан с **официальным или высоким**  стилем, а я связываю эту букву с **моим собственным стилем** в разговорной речи. Он особенный, **стилизованный** под старину. А стилизация (в общем случае) влияет на решение этой задачи. Только и всего.

*Все равно **нельзя**? Ну ладно, просто хотелось быть **вежливым**...*

P.S. (в сторону) **Странно как-то.** Ведь само правило называется [Прописные буквы в особом стилистическом употреблении](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=93). Вот и у меня оно **особое**...

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** Впрочем, если вы не хотите очень уж расстраивать окружающих, то писать надо правильно и только правильно. Ну это, конечно, смотря кому вы пишете...

https://dzen.ru/a/XUr40MSfKQCt8H_A